# Sexy validator for uniqueness with :scope constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

In a Ruby on Rails 3 application, I have invitations. Here is the model:

```
class TeamInvitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team

  validates :email, :presence => true, :format => RFC822::EMAIL
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :scope => :team_id
end
```

How can I refactor the uniqueness validation to include it into the validates method?

According to the documentation, the key `:uniqueness` should be a boolean, but in my case i want specify the scope. How can I do that (if possible)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
:uniqueness => { :scope => :team_id }
```

I haven't, but I know other ones can accept a hash.  Might be worth a shot.

Answer (score -1):

you can try :uniqueness => true

Comment: Please answer specificly the asked question. Romain Tribe said that he needs to specify the scope and boolean value is not good enough, so obviously your answer is not valid.